# How to get Facebook page cover photo using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get Facebook **page cover photo** using iOS SDK,
 From the parsed json result I am getting , the below result but,  couldn't get cover photo from there .

```
{
    actions =     (
                {
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/100007281559316/posts/1487360021516702";
            name = Comment;
        },
                {
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/100007281559316/posts/1487360021516702";
            name = Like;
        }
    );
    "created_time" = "2014-10-10T04:09:22+0000";
    description = "Loneliness is a good feeling when it is created by Ourself. But . .it is the worst feeling when it is Gifted by others.\nExpecting your Opinion  ekantatha@gmail.com";
    from =     {
        id = 100007281543425252416;
        name = "Hari Krishna";
    };
    icon = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif";
    id = "100007281559316_1487360021516702";
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/Ekantatha";
    message = "https://www.facebook.com/Ekantatha";
    name = "\U0d0f\U0d15\U0d3e\U0d28\U0d4d\U0d24\U0d24";
    picture = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/c6.0.200.200/p200x200/1779801_631456453593885_482158404_n.jpg?oh=8f766377fc71b8e3703e330067a70ebc&oe=54C1FF93&__gda__=1421213700_5f4ec6aea535e630c1a5a1eace45f34b";
    privacy =     {
        allow = "";
        deny = "";
        description = "Only Me";
        friends = "";
        networks = "";
        value = SELF;
    };
    properties =     (
                {
            name = Community;
            text = "1,102 like this";
        }
    );
    "status_type" = "shared_story";
    type = link;
    "updated_time" = "2014-10-10T04:09:22+0000";
}
```

**Edit :**

I want to display my cell like this so I needed cover photo for this. from the json result I am not getting the page Id. How can I get the cover photo of the page by using iOS SDK ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated solution.

```
var basicUserData = ["fields": "cover,picture,id,birthday,email"]

FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me",
    parameters: basicUserData,
    HTTPMethod: "GET") {
        (connection:FBRequestConnection!, result, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                print(result!)
            }
        }
```

The Parse team recommended getting FB profile picture by accessing the https://graph.facebook.com/(facebookId)/picture?type=large  Make sure to replace  with the user's Facebook Id. [Here is the discussion](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-a-facebook-or-twitter-users-profile-picture)

Notes:

- **username** field is deprecated after FacebookSDK v2
- **"/me"** is the correct endpoint not **"me"**
- [This gist shows many other interactions with the Facebook Graph](https://gist.github.com/ekoneil/3178821)

Comment: I need to get the cover photo of the Facebook page. not users cover photo.

Comment: just add cover to the fields string array

Answer (score 1):

For IOS;
I have used https://graph.facebook.com/facebookuserid?fields=cover link but it did not work. When I search Facebook SDK documentation, I see the answer that works. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@?fields=cover", [user objectForKey:@"id"]]
                  completionHandler:^(
                                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error
                                      ) {
                      NSLog(@"%@",[[result objectForKey:@"cover"]objectForKey:@"source"]);
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```

Result is a type of a Dictionary. You can see the link of user's cover photo under "cover" tag and its "source" tag also.

Answer (score 0):

That's a post JSON you're showing here, which has nothing to do with requesting the Page's cover.

The latter can be done via calling

```
GET /{Page_ID/?fields=id,name,cover
```

where `{Page_ID/` is the ID or the name of the Page in question. For CocaCola, the result looks like

```
{
  "id": "40796308305", 
  "name": "Coca-Cola", 
  "cover": {
    "cover_id": "10152297032458306", 
    "offset_x": 0, 
    "offset_y": 0, 
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/625442_10152297032458306_574021701_n.jpg?oh=54a129979e8786632b41e445db571749&oe=54B094E9&__gda__=1421627392_0061b39b7d81a3356a2b8a82a65b3839"
  }
}
```

Comment: from the json result not getting page Id. so how can I use it ?

Comment: I don't understand. You're posting a user-generated post JSON, which is something totally different!!! There's no Page involved, so this can't work!

Comment: I am getting this json results from me/home.How can I get the page Id for, getting cover photo.

Comment: What Page_ID, this was not posted by a Page... Do you mean the user's cover photo?

Comment: yes, this is a user likes a page, not posted by the page.

Comment: That's not correct. No like involved here. I don't understand what you want to do, and you don't answer to my questions.